# How to fix the error occured when using NbClust() with dissimilarity matrix?

Tags: r, compiler-errors, cluster-analysis

My data has both categorical and continuous variables. I want to use NbClust() function in order to determine the optimal number of clusters(k). So I used the dissimilarity matrix and set the distance as NULL, but I got an error when using the code bellow:

```
 res.nb <- NbClust(diss=gower_dist_gender,distance=NULL, min.nc = 1, 
              max.nc = 30,method = "complete", index ="all")
```

How can I fix this error?what is the problem?

The error is:Error in NbClust(data = NULL, diss = gower_dist_gender, distance = NULL,  : 
Data matrix is needed. Only frey, mcclain, cindex, sihouette and dunn can be computed.

I thank all of you in advance.

Comment: How was `gower_dist_gender` computed?

Comment: gower_dist_gender <- daisy(mydata , metric = "gower")

Answer (score 0):

Some of the indexes *require* numerical data.

Therefore, this function cannot be used on your data set, *unless* you **select only indexes that do not require coordinates**.

To quote the error message:

> Data matrix is needed. Only frey, mcclain, cindex, sihouette and dunn can be computed.

Only these indexes work on the distance matrix. All other indexes need numeric coordinates.

Comment: :As my data is mixed I used the dissimilarity matrix to satisfy these conditions(I mean whenever the numeric data is needed I used dissimilarity matrix). It seems that it doesn't work . Why can't the dissimilarity matrix compensate these shortage?

Comment: :The indexes that mentioned in the error (frey,mcclain,cindex and dunn)don't work though. I can just use silhouette and this index works well.but I need the results of more indexes to be sure about the number of my data's clusters.

Comment: The methods mentioned in the error including frey,mcclain,dunn,cindex when were used in the code following error occuerd:Error in rep(NA, nn) : invalid 'times' argument
just the silhoutte method works well.I will be so thankful for any help or guidence.

Comment: I don't use R (I hate its syntax), so I can't give you a tutorial. But for the other indexes: read the definition of the index, and you should see why they only work with numeric data.

Comment: For example Davies-Bouldin uses the distance to the cluster *center*, where the center is computed as the arithmetic mean - so it needs numerical attributes. So it makes perfect sense if NBclust cannot compute DB index.